# How to make a label's text look good on top of an image?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, uilabel

I have a `UIButton`, on which I set a `UIImage` (by using `set(_:for:)` method). After that, I add a label on it with some text (It should be white). The problem is: When I use some photos, which have bright colours (close to white), it's hard to see some characters of the text. Here how it looks like (the button isn't very big, hence the quality of the image is low, too):

[image]

I've tried to add a `UIView` between the button and the label and to manipulate its `alpha`, but that doesn't help. If you know how the problem can be solved (without changing text's colour), I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is to set the label's background color to a partially transparent black color. Then maybe round the labels corners for a nice look.

```
let label = ... // your label 
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.4) // adjust alpha as desired
label.layer.cornerRadius = 4 // adjust as desired
```

Another option, instead of adding a background to the label, is to use attribute text for the label and give the white text a black outline.

```
let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
    .strokeWidth: -2.0,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) // Use whatever font you want
]
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Grand Royal", attributes: attrs)
label.attributedText = attrStr
```

Yet another option is to setup the label with a shadow:

```
let label = ... // your label 
label.shadowColor = .black
label.shadowSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

The shadow can be created using attribute text and this gives you more control:

```
let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3
let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    .shadow: shadow,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
]
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Grand Royal", attributes: attrs)
label.attributedText = attrStr
```

This puts a halo around the text. Adjust the shadow properties to suit your needs.

Comment: Well, that works, but sometimes my label is taller, so in that case it will close the image behind of it. Is there a way to check image's colour (or maybe tint)?

Comment: Yes, you can analyze the colors of the image and decide on the best text color but for many images no choice of text color will work well. At least part of the text will be hard to see if the image has light and dark areas where the text will be. I've updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works, but honestly speaking, the text looks a bit ugly, in this case. Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: Adjust the stroke width and colors as desired. But these are just suggestions. Your question mentions a failed attempt to put a view behind the label but you don't state why it didn't help. Update your question with clear and specific details about that attempt. And explain how that attempt would give different results from simply setting the label's background color.

Comment: I added a few more options for adding a shadow to the text. Give those a try and play around with the properties to get slightly different results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Shadows, make it as close as possible to what I was looking for :)